# Azure App Service - 'Ghost' file in Kudu vs Winscp-ftp client

Tags: azure, kudu, azure-appservice

I deployed a newly created Asp.Net Core web application to an Azure app service using ftp, while enabling **delete existing files**, directly from VS 2019.

Now whenever I view the content of the wwroot folder using Winscp, the result is as expected and I see the latest output from my local build. But whenever I view the contents of the folder in Kudu, the list of files is outdated/reflects previous local builds outputs (screenshots below from winscp and from kudu in the browser).

What is going on here ?

This is also breaking my app, since my app's initialization code cannot read an xml file that I see in winscp, but is not visible when I navigate to the folder in kudu.

I already tried restarting the app service multiple times, to no avail.

What am I missing ??

wwroot contents from kudu
[image: wwroot content from kudu]

wwroot contents from winscp (files order alphabetically, the vue middleware should be displayed before web.config)

[image]